# Controlar promesas en un ciclo foreach Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, express, promesas

Estoy trabajando en subir unos archivos y lo hago de dos formas, ya que aveces viene un archivo que es un `object` y aveces viene un `array` depende si el usuario sube uno o más de un archivo

```
if ( Array.isArray(files.invoices) ) {

    const results: Array<string> = []
    const errs:    Array<string> = []
    files.invoices.forEach( ( invoice: any ) => {
        uploadFile( invoice )
        .then( (  message: string ) => results.push( message ) )
        .catch( ( message: string ) => errs.push( message ) )
    })
    console.log( results, errs )

} else {
    // Si es un solo archivo lo procesamos
    const invoice = files.invoices
    uploadFile( invoice )
    .then( (  message: string ) => res.status( 200 ).json( { message } ) )
    .catch( ( message: string ) => res.status( 403 ).json( { message } ) )
}
```

Esta es la función que hace la operación de subir el archivo

```
const uploadFile = (file: any ): Promise < string > => {

    return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {

        // Si no es un JSON, rechamamos la promesa, contrario copiamos el archivo
        if (file.mimetype === 'application/json') {
            file.mv(`./uploads/${ file.name }`, (err: any) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(`No pudo ser copiado el archivo ${ file.name }`)
                } else {
                    resolve(file.name)
                }
            })
        } else {
            reject(`El archivo ${ file.name } no tiene el formato correcto (${ file.mimetype })`)
        }
    })
}
```

Cuando subo un archivo funciona de maravilla, me regresa el nombre del archivo y eso lo almaceno en una base de datos. El problema es cuando subo más de uno, si los sube, pero no estoy obteniendo los nombres. Los nombres los quiero almacenar en un arreglo que definí como `results` cuando termine de ciclar el `forEach` debería tener los nombres de los ficheros que se subieron, sin embargo me aparece vacío el arreglo.

¿Cómo puedo controlarlo? El código que estoy implementado quizá no sea el mejor, y estoy dispuesto a leer propuestas de mejora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all) puede ser la solucion.

```javascript
 //creas un arreglo que contenga las promesasa
const promesas = []
//Obtienes solo las promesas
files.invoices.forEach(x=> promesas.push(uploadFile(x)))
        //Promise.all se encarga de esperar a que todas las promesas se resuelvan
        // y retorna un arreglo con la respuesta equivalente a cada promesa. 
        Promise.all(promesas)
        .then( (  message: string[] ) => results.concat(message) )
        .catch( ( message: string ) => console.log(message ))
    })
```

> El método Promise.all(iterable) devuelve una promesa que termina
> correctamente cuando todas las promesas en el argumento iterable han
> sido concluídas con éxito, o bien rechaza la petición con el motivo
> pasado por la primera promesa que es rechazada.

El problema reside en que cada promesa se ejecuta de manera asíncrona en las iteraciones que hace el `forEach`. Esto provoca que la ejecución de la lógica termine antes de que las promesas sean resueltas o rechazadas provocando comportamientos extranos.

---

**Edicion**

En el caso de que quieras que continue aunque algunas fallen utiliza [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Es similar en funcionamiento que `Promise.all()`, solo que no se detiene si falla.

Comment: Está casi perfecto Angel, como pudiera controlar que si una falla, no me rompa las otras?

Comment: Edito la respuesta.

Comment: De echo, puedes hacer todo sin el `else`